# Pure Render Element rendering with no changes ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVpVXW

If you open up the console and type into any of the input fields, you will notice that the `render` method for the `FormTextbox` component that has changed is the only one that is called however the `render` method of all ten of the `FormElement` components are called even though only one of them had a child that changed.

Why would the `render` method of all `FormElement` components be called when 9 of them did not have any changes and it is using the Pure Render Mixin (and the child component also using the Pure Render Mixin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this works as expected because you are composing components. `PureRender` works by checking that props are identical; however, since you are passing using `props.children`, the prop equivalence check will fail (object/array equivalency in JavaScript is a tricky business), and thus the component is re-rendered. Its subtree is *not* updated as it has primitive props which have not changed.

---

For proof, check out [this updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPoPEo) where I explicitly override `shouldComponentUpdate`. Indeed you will see in the logs that the comparison `this.props.children == nextProps.children` is **`false`**.

From the [PureRender Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html):

> This only **shallowly compares** the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce false-negatives for deeper differences.

(emphasis mine)